# how to move a softbody object after simulation ends

Tags: soft-body

I used the softbody simulation that ends at frame 10

[image]

I want to move a softbody object at frame 11 from A to B.

Somebody help me~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this isn't possible.

A workaround would be this:

Create a copy of your object with same subdivision. Delete soft body modifier on your copy. Add a surface deform modifier

[image]

click bind.

Add a keyframe on frame 10 to show your softbody object.

Add a keyframe on frame 11 to hide your softbody object.

Animate your copy movement from frame 11 to 20.

Add a keyframe on frame 10 to hide your copied object.
Add a keyframe on frame 11 to show your copied object.